# How can I share my current GPS location from google maps?

Tags: gps, google-maps, geolocation

I'm at a screen such as this and I'd like to share the exact GPS location of the blue marker (not just the approximate address). The only way I've found is to get directions to somewhere, share the link to clipboard, paste it somewhere, copy out the starting coordinates, paste them back into maps and then share that. Is there a better way?

[image]

Comment: If you're using WhatsApp, there's an easy "share location" feature.

Comment: Thanks. Google hangouts has one too but I have to share it with a contract before I can copy the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I can do on the current Play Store version of Google maps. (9.22.1)

From your screenshot, it appears that your GPS position is not accurate. In "location settings", choose "high accuracy". Get out where there's no concrete roof above your phone.

Let GPS get a good fix on your position.

Zoom in on the screen. Press and hold on the "blue dot" for a menu to appear with details of the location.

Then click the "share" button.

Choose "copy to clipboard", if that's what you want. Else choose an app to share your location info.

Comment: When I press and hold I get a marker dropped near the blue dot which I can share, but I can never get it exactly on the blue dot.

Comment: @jozxyqk Try zooming in on screen to drop the marker exactly on the blue dot. Plus, it's almost impossible to get accuracy upto 5m.

Comment: Aah, good thinking. Seems close enough after zooming in. When the map quality is poor as in the screenshot it's hard to get a sense of how far off I really am. I'm guessing that's what the pale blue circle is good for.

Comment: @jozxyqk pale blue circle exists because you're not getting a good GPS fix. Try standing outdoors with "high accuracy" option enabled in "location settings"

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is on, but zooming in as far as I go still has a circle, albeit small.

Comment: @jozxyqk yes, like I said, you'll almost never get accuracy upto 5 metres, even standing outside on a clear sunny day.