# How can I copy GPS coordinates from a marker in Google Maps app?

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way to get/copy GPS coordinates from a  marker on the Google Maps app? When I drop a marker by holding down on a spot, I get the coordinates in the field. But, when I tap in the field to copy them, the numbers change to the city location.

I should have added this at the start: I am using Version 9.69.1.

Comment: Close Voters : NOT a duplicate of [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/140751/131553) as that pertains to old version and that method doesn't work - I was about to vote it as duplicate :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite easy

When you drop a pin you get coordinates in the search bar that can't be copied as you observed

To do that, on the left bottom you will find *More Info*. Tapping on that will take you to next screen where you can see the coordinates and long press to copy to clipboard ! You will get a toast confirmation as shown and paste it wherever

[image]

Maps version `9.67.1`

(Your GPS needs to switched on with the faint blue circle showing up before you drop the pin)

Comment: beeshyarms: That worked. Exactly what I needed. : )  I am very happy with this answer. I used to have a separate GPS app. But, they started adding advertisements to the point where it was unusable. I figured that there had to be a way to use Google Maps app since I had seen the GPS coordinates there.

Comment: Glad to help :)