# Google Maps, copying GPS coordinates, getting plus codes

Tags: google-maps, samsung-galaxy-s7

This question explains how to get the GPS coordinates

[How can I copy GPS coordinates from a marker in Google Maps app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/189551/131553)

I did all that but I come up with a "plus code", this doesn't work for me.  How to get the coordinates instead of plus code?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot please?

Answer (score 1):

I answered the question you referred to and  checked the reason

**Your GPS is off**

Switch on your GPS ( wait for the faint blue circle to show up indicating your location) and then drop marker ; you can't get GPS coordinates keeping the GPS off ! (not to sound snarky )

Comment: Amended by answer in linked question to make it clear

Comment: it is on and you don't sound snarky, it's all good.

Comment: In that case, you can *accept* the answer by ticking the green arrow next to it to indicate that the solution provided solved your problem